# Uploading File (Downloadable Information) Magento 1.9x

Tags: magento-1.9

Weird problem: When I try to upload a product file in the "downloadable information" section it begins to load but does not complete. Then it returns automatically to the admin login screen.

[image]

[image]

Is there someone who can help me, please ?

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this issue after performing the `patch 11314`.

I found my issue was in this file `app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php`:

```
return (bool) Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_ALLOW_SID_FOR_ADMIN_AREA);
```

This was always returning false resulting in the upload request returning the Magento admin login screen.

I managed to resolve it by adding the new row to the `core_config_data` table with the path of `web/session/use_admin_sid` and `value of 1`, example:

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`config_id`, `scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, 'default', '0', 'web/session/use_admin_sid', '1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```